# How to attach file in sharepoint list using sand box solution

Tags: 2013, visual-studio

I have tried so many ways and I searched so many articles, I didn't get any solution for attaching file in a SharePoint list using `sand box solution`.

I got solution using `farm solutions`. How can we achieve it using `Sand Box solution`?

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        try
        {
            using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPList list = oSPWeb.Lists["FileAttach"];
                    //Add a new item in the List
                    SPListItem itemToAdd = list.Items.Add();
                    SPAttachmentCollection attachmentCollection = itemToAdd.Attachments;

                     Stream attachmentStream;
                    Byte[] attachmentContent;
                    // Get the file from the file upload control
                    if (this.flprojectieadformat.HasFile)
                    {
                        attachmentStream = this.flprojectieadformat.PostedFile.InputStream;
                        attachmentContent = new Byte[attachmentStream.Length];
                        attachmentStream.Read(attachmentContent, 0, (int)attachmentStream.Length);
                        attachmentStream.Close();
                        attachmentStream.Dispose();
                        attachmentCollection.Add(this.flprojectieadformat.FileName, attachmentContent);
                    }
                    itemToAdd["Title"] = TextBox1.Text;
                    itemToAdd.Update();

                }
            }
        }
            catch(Exception ex)
        {
            }


    }
```

Comment: What is the error you got in sandboxed solution? Show some code also

Comment: I got solution in farm ,but i didn't  any solution for sandbox.

Comment: It should be the same for both. Write the same code and let me know

Comment: It is not showing any error and attachment not added

Comment: Then show your code.

Comment: check above snipet

Comment: follow the link http://www.microsofttechnology.net/2013/10/attach-file-to-sharepoint-list-item-by.html

Comment: Already i seen above link and followed same way but it showing error

Comment: I have tried your in code in my server. Your code did not work for farm solution. Then I wrote my own and that worked on farm not in sandboxed solution.

Comment: I need sandbox solutions